# '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' pandas function for getting threshold

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, tuples

I have a df

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3], 
                  
                           'Text':['This num dogs and cats is (111)888-8780 and other',
                              'dont block cow 23 here',
                              'cat two num: dog  and cows here'], 
                                   
                                  'Match':[[('cats', 86), ('dogs', 86), ('dogs', 29)],
                                   [('cow', 33), ('dont', 57), ('cow', 100)], 
                                             [('cat', 100), ('dog', 100), ('cows', 86)] ]
                      })
```

And it looks like this

```
    ID                       Text                                   Match
0   1   This num dogs and cats is (111)888-8780 and other   [(cats, 86), (dogs, 86), (dogs, 29)]
1   2   dont block cow 23 here                              [(cow, 33), (dont, 57), (cow, 100)]
2   3   cat two num: dog and cows here                      [(cat, 100), (dog, 100), (cows, 86)]
```

My goal is to create a function that only keeps certain item within `Match` column that are above a certain threshold (e.g. 80) so I tried the following

```
def threshold(column):
    
    column_tup = column
    
    keep_tuple = []
    
    for col in column_tup:
        if column_tup > 80:
            keep_tuple.append()
    
    return pd.Series([keep_tuple], index = ['Keep_Words'])

df_thresh = df.join(df.apply(lambda x: threshold(x),  axis = 1))
```

But this gives me an error

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

My goal is to get a df with a new column `Keep_Words` that looks like the following where only score above 85 are kept in `Keep_Words`

```
     ID    Text    Match   Keep_Words
0   1      data    data   [(cats, 86), (dogs, 86)]              
1   2      data    data   [(cow, 100)]
2   3      data    data   [(cat, 100), (dog, 100)]
```

How do I alter my code to reach my goal?

Comment: `col > 80` instead of `column_tup > 80`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to change only the `Match` column, you might as well only pass that column to `apply`:

```
df.Match.apply(threshold)
```

where we don't use `axis` argument anymore since it is a Series we are applying over and it has only one axis anyway.

Then, each time your function is called, a row of `df.Match` will be passed and get assigned to the function argument, so we can rename the function signature to:

```
def threshold(match_row):
```

for readability.

So, `match_row` will be a list, e.g., in the first turn it'll be `[(cats, 86), (dogs, 86), (dogs, 29)]`. We can iterate over as you did but with 2 for-loop variable as:

```
for name, val in match_row:
```

so that `name` will become the first entry of each tuple and `val` is the second. Now we can do the filtering:

```
keep_tuple = []
for name, val in match_row:
    if val > 85:
        keep_tuple.append((name, val))
```

which is fine but not so Pythonic because there is list comprehensions:

```
keep_tuple = [(name, val) for name, val in match_row if val > 85]
```

Lastly we can return this as you did:

```
return pd.Series([keep_tuple], index=["Keep_Words"])
```

As for calling and assignment, we can `join` as you did:

```
df_thresh = df.join(df.Match.apply(threshold))
```

All in all,

```
def threshold(match_row):
    keep_tuple = [(name, val) for name, val in match_row if val > 85]
    return pd.Series([keep_tuple], index=["Keep_Words"])

df_thresh = df.join(df.Match.apply(threshold))
```

which gives

```
>>> df_thresh

   ID                                               Text                                 Match                            Keep_Words
0   1  This num dogs and cats is (111)888-8780 and other  [(cats, 86), (dogs, 86), (dogs, 29)]              [(cats, 86), (dogs, 86)]
1   2                             dont block cow 23 here   [(cow, 33), (dont, 57), (cow, 100)]                          [(cow, 100)]
2   3                    cat two num: dog  and cows here  [(cat, 100), (dog, 100), (cows, 86)]  [(cat, 100), (dog, 100), (cows, 86)]
```

---

Lastly, for the error you got: I didn't get that error but the infamous

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

error, which was because of this line

```
if column_tup > 80:
```

where `column_tup` is a whole row as a `pd.Series` but its behaviour in boolean context is ambiguous.